# Is it legal to pick locks to gain access to an area you're allowed to be in, in Canada?

Tags: criminal-law, canada, trespass

After a bit of discussion regarding my answer for [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/164272/employer-planning-on-making-a-change-that-im-prepared-to-quit-over-how-should/164314?noredirect=1#comment532451_164314) in the Workplace Stackexchange, I got to wondering:

Is it legal to pick a lock to gain access to an area you're authorized to enter in Canada, without getting permission to pick the lock? For instance, you're legally allowed to enter your workplace, so would it be legal to pick a lock to gain access to it, rather than using the intended methods of opening the lock? If you're allowed to go there, you wouldn't be committing a crime like Criminal Trespass or Breaking and Entering, right? Are there any other laws that would make this illegal there?

Comment: Note that you're also bypassing the security system that records entry of the employee.

Comment: "For instance, you're legally allowed to enter your workplace," when permitted. You do not have carte blanche to enter your workplace at will- I know if I broke into mine after hours I'd be answering a lot of questions.

Comment: @Studoku Sure. I want to know about picking locks to access an area you're permitted to enter, during the time you're permitted to enter it (e.g. your work, during work hours).

Comment: If I understand correctly, trespass laws vary by province, so to get a reliable answer you may need to provide more detail.  (Breaking & entering is a federal offense in Canada, but [its definition requires the offender to commit an indictable offense](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-348.html), or intend to do so, so it's probably not applicable here.)

Answer (score 2):

### Are you “legally allowed to enter your workplace“?

Or are you legally allowed during normal work hours when the premises is open for business? Permission to enter can be conditional and a locked door is generally a big denial of permission.

However, let’s assume you have permission to be inside. Do you have permission to break in? That’s a question that will turn on the facts. If the owner says you didn’t have permission then breaking in is a crime.